# How to remove the border around the address bar of chrome when the user scrolls down my webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to implement a view for my website where the address bar border get hidden when the user scrolls down my webpage. Is this possible?

I initially tried hiding the address bar itself, but soon found out that the modern day browsers have removed this option due to security and phishing reasons. So, now I want to at least hide the border so that when the user scrolls down, the bar itself appears as if it is a part of the page and not detached.

Looking for an answer ASAP. Thanks

Comment: so basically you want to hide the scroll bar ?

Comment: no. i want to have the same effect on the desktop view as the mobile view. Meaning, if the user scrolls down, the address bar gets hidden

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible. Sorry but you can't do it, it's a feature of Google Chrome you can't do it by yourself.

Comment: Yes Haviv. I agree with you. No way I can implement this feature. So I have dropped the plans of implementing this. Thanks

Comment: @ritzzy26 you don't need to upvote, you need to accept the answer so the community will be able to see the answer to that question. Just click on the empty V next to the upvote button. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23138/how-to-accept-the-answer-on-stack-overflow

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var winFeature =
    'location=no,toolbar=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes';
window.open('Result.html','null',winFeature);
```

Comment: This does not solve the issue. I already had done this. This code snippet pops up another pop up of the same page that you are asking to open . Also, if the user has disabled / blocked pop up in his browsers, this is of no use